# Set initial value of mat-select in a different format than the desired return value

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am trying to initialize a form control with a specific value but I cannot find a way to achieve my requirement. I have the following code :

**HTML template :**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName='businessUnit'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let businessUnit of businessUnitsArray" [value]="[businessUnit.id, businessUnit.costCenter]">{{businessUnit.businessUnitName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TYPESCRIPT component :**

```js
this.updateDepartmentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  departmentName:   [this.dialogData.departmentName, Validators.required ],
  departmentNumber: [this.dialogData.departmentNumber, Validators.required ],
  businessUnit:     [this.dialogData.businessUnitInfo[1], Validators.required ]
});
```

`this.dialogData.businessUnitInfo[1]` contains a string equal to the *mat-option* that I would like selected initially upon form initialization. I know that in order to achieve this I would have to change the value of the [value] tag of the *mat-option* to be the data that I would want, in this case `this.dialogData.businessUnitInfo[1]`.

However, my problem is that upon submitting the form, the data that I want returned in relation to the selected *mat-option* is not the string of the selected option, but rather an array containing the selected option's id and costCenter which are two variables linked to the selected *mat-option*, which is why I need to keep the [value] tag equal the the array --> [businessUnit.id, businessUnit.costCenter].

With the code being written as it is, the *mat-select* doesn't get initialized with any value. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks to all for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use dynamically created array as selected value. Array equality is checked over references so no matter what value you give your form control it wont match with any of the option values. What you can do is :

1. Not to use an array and just use id as selected value
2. Use predifined array of arrays and set the selected value among the array

> As 1. option is clear enough here is the sample for 2. option :

```
this.businessSelections = this.businessUnitsArray.map(bu=> [bu.id, bu.costCenter]); // initialize a property with an array of arrays
```

> In your template :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName='businessUnit'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let businessUnit of businessUnitsArray;let ix = index"
                  [value]="businessSelections[ix]">
                 {{businessUnit.businessUnitName}} 
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

> Set the initial value :

```
this.updateDepartmentForm.patchValue({ businessUnit : this.businessSelections[0] })
// or query your array with the parameter you passed to your dialog
const buId = dialogData.businessUnitInfo[0]; // it contains id i think
const selected = this.businessSelections.find(r=> r[0] === buId); // find the selection with the id
this.updateDepartmentForm.patchValue({ businessUnit : selected });
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Wouldn't the last line make it so that the initial value will always be the same no matter what with 0 being the index? 

```this.updateDepartmentForm.patchValue({ businessUnit : this.businessSelections[0] })```

How would I actually pass it the desired index?

Comment: Keep in mind that this form is in a dialog and that the variable stating which option should be selected resides in dialogData.businessUnitInfo[1] as a string (passed to the dialog upon its creation). I also have the option to use the index "0" of this same array that is actually the id. Could I?

Comment: @RemyA. Giving 0 was just an example. You can filter your array as desired and patch the found value as you like. Can you give an example of that string passed into dialog.

Comment: Sure. The dialogData.businessUnitInfo array contains the following :

`['wAgIw0JA3J1DzRSBsbCZ', 'BusinessUnit1', '4501']`.

The mat-select has the following options : BuisinessUnit1, BusinessUnit2, BusinessUnit3. That is why I was passing this.dialogData.businessUnitInfo[1] to get the desired dropdown option.